# Overwrite nested javascript function

Tags: javascript

I am making a simple chrome extension and want to overwrite a javascript function on a page. The javascript is too complex for me too understand. This is a part of the code:

```
}), define("components/Payout", ["react", "game-logic/clib", "game-logic/stateLib"], function(e, t, n) {
    var r = e.DOM;
    return e.createClass({
        displayName: "Payout",
        mixins: [e.addons.PureRenderMixin],
        propTypes: {
            engine: e.PropTypes.object.isRequired
        },
        getInitialState: function() {
            return {
                payout: 0
            }
        },
        componentDidMount: function() {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(this.draw)
        },
        draw: function() {
            if (this.isMounted()) {
                var e = t.calcGamePayout(t.getElapsedTimeWithLag(this.props.engine));
                e ? this.setState({
                    payout: e * n.currentPlay(this.props.engine).bet
                }) : this.setState({
                    payout: null
                }), window.requestAnimationFrame(this.draw)
            }
        },
        render: function() {
            var e = n.currentPlay(this.props.engine).bet < 1e4 ? 2 : 0;
            return r.span({
                id: "payout"
            }, t.formatSatoshis(this.state.payout, e))
        }
    })
}),
```

The function i want to 'hijack' is the "render" function. How would i go about that from an external JS file?

What i want is to replace the content of that function with something adjusted.

Comment: You first will need to overwrite `define` (or mess with the exposed? internals of the module loader that is used here). Then you'll be able to access the `.prototype.render` property and hijack it.

Answer (score 1):

If the variable `obj` contains the object returned by that code, you can assign to `obj.render`:

```
obj.render = function() {
    // your code here
};
```

Note that your code won't be able to use the `r`, `t`, or `n` variables like the original `render` function does. Those variables are only available in the original scope, and your function is outside that scope.

If you want to be able to call the original render method, you can do:

```
var orig_render = obj.render;
obj.render = function() {
    var oldrender = orig_render.bind(this);
    // your code here, call oldrender() to call original version
};
```

This is called [monkey patching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch).